# set javascript variable value mvc c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using asp.net mvc c# and trying to set variable value in 'allow:'.
But since it contains @ symbol the entire page is not rendering.
Is there any way to include @ symbol in variable value without affecting razor rendering.

```
@section TopScripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/alphanumeric/jquery.alphanumeric.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtUserId").numeric();
            $("#txtPassword").alphanum({
                allow: "~!@#$%^*",
                disallow: '&,;()'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: try use Unicode char *commercial at* in a js string: `"~!#$%^*\u0040"`